# tight_layout() doesn't work on the first call

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I'm using **Spider + Qt** as Graphics backend.
In the script I do some subplots and finally call `tight_layout()`, but it does not work:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(..)
axs[..].plot()
...
fig.tight_layout()
```

Then I call the `fig.tight_layout()` again from the IPython console (I use the **fig** instance of the above plotted figure), and (o, miracle!) it works out! 
What is wrong? I suspect, that Qt processes plotting requests with some delay (at least, the graph window appears after the all script is finished), but don't understand how to fix that, except manually call `fig.tight_layout()` afterwards

So, the main problem, that `fig.tight_layout()` works, but only when the figure is already displayed on the screen. It does not work for new figures, but if I run the script for the second time and use the same figure name (so, the same figure window) - it works correctly. Or if I call it from IPython console.

P.S. The solution, suggested by Trenton McKinney (`fig, axs = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)`) works, so the question may be marked as Solved

Comment: Spider shows the figure without `plt.show()`. I tried to add it, but without any effect

Comment: fig, axs = plt.subplots(tight_layout=True)

Comment: Hmm, looks working, thanks! Do you know, why original code does not work?

Comment: Nope, I just may be the way spider /qt render the plot

Comment: This question should probably be reopend and an answer be added with that suggestion.